# .gitlab-ci servicio mysql en Django

Tags: python, mysql, django, gitlab-ci

Estoy aprendiendo a utilizar Gitlab CI y estoy intentando configurar el fichero `.gitlab-ci` para ejecutarlo en mi proyecto con Django.

- Tengo el siguiente fichero `.gitlab-ci` (es un ejemplo, no está completo):

```
stages:
    - test
 
variables:
    MYSQL_DATABASE: $DB_NAME
    MYSQL_USER: $DB_USER
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: $DB_PASSWORD

services:
    - mysql:8.0

test: 
    image: alpine:3.13
    stage: test
    script:
        - ...(up the app)...
```

- He configurado las variables de entorno en el Gitlab (Settings -> CI/CD -> Variables), e.g:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

- Y tengo la siguiente configuración el el fichero `settings.py` con el apartado de BD:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': getenv('DB_NAME'),
        'USER': getenv('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD': getenv('DB_PASSWORD'),
        'HOST': getenv('DB_HOST'),
        'PORT': getenv('DB_PORT'),
        'TEST' : {
            'NAME' : f"test_{getenv('DB_NAME')}",
        }
    }
}
```

Cuando se ejecuta, todo se instala correctamente pero cuando llega al apartado de ejecutar los tests de django arroja el siguiente error:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2005, "Unknown MySQL server host 'mysql' (-2)")
```

¿Por qué no conecta si en al documentación de Gitlab indica que se puede utilizar `mysql` como host de la BD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Después de revisar y recibir sugerencias de algunos usuarios de la comunidad (gracias @abulafia @padaleiana @Trauma), se me ocurrió mirar algo que debí hacer mucho antes: revisar los logs desde el principio aunque el pipeline sea muy extenso.

Entre tantos logs, unas de las líneas indicaban lo siguiente:

```
2021-04-11T00:04:33.635793560Z     You need to specify one of the following:
2021-04-11T00:04:33.635798376Z     - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
2021-04-11T00:04:33.635802359Z     - MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD
2021-04-11T00:04:33.635805957Z     - MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD
```

Por lo que es necesario, por supuesto, predefinir la contraseña del usuario root para el servicio mysql o permitir una contraseña vacía.

La única variable necesaria para que se levante el service de mysql es una de las 3 mencionadas anteriormente:

- MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
- MYSQL_ALLOW_EMPTY_PASSWORD
- MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD

Mi gitlab-ci file quedaría de la siguiente manera:

```
variables:
    MYSQL_DATABASE: $DB_NAME
    MYSQL_USER: $DB_USER
    MYSQL_PASSWORD: $DB_PASSWORD
    MYSQL_HOST: $DB_HOST
    MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: $DB_ROOT_PASSWORD
```

Y exportaría la variable DB_ROOT_PASSWORD con la contraseña dentro de la configuración: Settings -> CI/CD -> Variables. Gracias a todos por la ayuda.